# What is a format for writing Introduction part for a economics/finance paper?

Tags: style

I read a couple of papers in economics and finance areas. I saw that in the different papers they used different styles. Is there any outline for writing an introduction with easy-to-follow instructions?

Comment: Do you have an advisor?

Comment: Yes, I have, but they just ask me to read their previous papers to find their style, but it is quite strange for me.